# How to check CPU usage before running a Python script by shell_exec? Or alternative queuing approaches to prevent server overload?

Tags: python, php, web-applications, shell-exec

I have an Apache-based PHP website that:

- Accepts a document uploaded by a user (typically a text file)
- Runs a Python script over the uploaded file using shell_exec (this produces a text file output locally on the disk); the PHP code that runs the shell_exec looks something like `$result = shell_exec python3 memory_hog_script.py user_uploaded_text_file.txt`
- Shows the text output to the user

The Python script executed by PHP's shell_exec typically takes 5-10 seconds to be run, but uses open source libraries that take up a lot of memory/CPU (e.g. 50-70%) while it's being run.

More commonly now, I have multiple users uploading a file at the exact same time. When a handful of users upload a file at the same time, my CPU gets overloaded since a separate instance of the heavy memory hogging python file gets executed via shell_exec for each user. When this happens, the server crashes.

I'm trying to figure out what the best way is to handle this, and I had a few ideas but wasn't sure which one is the best approach / is feasible:

1. Before `shell_exec` gets run by PHP, check CPU usage and see if it is greater than a certain threshold (e.g. 70%); if so, wait 10 seconds and try again
2. Alternatively, I can check the database for current active uploads; if there are more than a certain threshold (e.g. 5 uploads), then do something
3. Create some sort of queueing system; I'm not sure what my options here, but I imagine there is a way to separate out the `shell_exec` into some kind of managed queue - I'm very happy to look into new technologies here, so if there are any approaches you can introduce me to, I'd love to dig deeper!

Any input would be much appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: Is there a need to get results as soon as possible.  Perhaps a cron job running during the quiet hours of the day (if there is such a thing).

Comment: Yes that's correct - users need to get the text output as soon as they're ready. Currently, they get the text output after being shown a loading screen for 5-10 seconds, and I would be happy to extend that loading screen wait time.